# Clicking Sound with the Bike Stopped

Tags: noise, clicking

I have a Giant E-Bike and I've just noticed that it makes a clicking sound when it is stopped, the front brake is applied and it's being pushed/pulled with the handlebars.

I've removed the brake calipers to check movement in the pads but this does not appear to be the problem.

Comment: Sounds like a loose headset to me - is the steering sloppy ?  Can you feel motion between the stem and the frame when doing the push/pull as described ?

Comment: Hi Criggie.  Thanks for your input.  I can't feel any motion between the stem and the frame but I tightened the headset anyway.  Noise is still there.  Just wondering if the forks themselves could be causing the noise. They are SR Suntour XCM.  Also, the top spacer in the headset allows the system to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

First thing I'd check is the headset assembly, even on a new bike. Eliminate it by dismantling, then greasing all the surfaces and reinstalling with careful adjustment. Even applies to brand new bicycles occasionally.

It could be something else, perhaps spokes moving or qr axle, the stem or some part of the brake as ideas. Whenever you're creak-hunting, check and grease or substitute only one thing at a time before testing it out so you can isolate the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advise.  What I did today was to tighten the headset and it appears to not have any movement when the bike is pushed/pulled with the brake on.  Should I take the headset apart and grease it, etc.? before looking at anything else.  Could the noise be coming from the forks?  It is a SR Suntour XCR and therefore not high end. Is there a way that the inner/outer shafts could hit.  Just wondering.  Really appreciate your help!  Oh since I'd don't have a torque wrench, I'm a touch cautious tigtening the center bolt of the head set.  Thanks!